# Iterate the AST

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I have this python code as an example

```
def myFunction(x):
    return filters.delta(x)


if starting:
    diagnostics.debug(myFunction(1))
    diagnostics.debug(myFunction(2))
```

`filters.delta` is a util function that the users of my application can use in their python scripts Above code should output

```
0
0
```

But it outputs

```
0
1
```

This is because my script preparser is too dumb for above usecase, the real parameters for the `filter.delta` function is `filters.delta(x, indexer)` my dumb preparser just adds the name of the parameters. So after preparse the above code would look like

```
def myFunction(x):
    return filters.delta(x, "x")
```

This will cause both calls to `myFunction` using the same indexer and the second calls overwrites the samples for the first call. So my goal is to use the AST module to parse the synstax tree and add the indexer to all functions in the chain. The result should look like

```
def myFunction(x, indexer):
    return filters.delta(x, indexer)


if starting:
    diagnostics.debug(myFunction(1, "1"))
    diagnostics.debug(myFunction(2, "2"))
```

Using the ast modele i can dump the script to a tree like

```
import ast
tree = ast.parse(script)
```

But I have not find any info on how to iterate the tree and when I find a function like `filters.delta` that needs the preparse I will iterate back up and add the argument to all function calls. Is this possible somehow?

Here is a real world example on what this software is used for

```
def filterAndroidSignal(axis):
    return filters.deadband(filters.continuousRotation(axis), 0.1)


def onUpdate():
    vJoy[0].x = filterAndroidSignal(android[0].yaw)
    vJoy[0].y = filterAndroidSignal(android[0].pitch)

if starting:
    android[0].update += onUpdate
```

Above code will fail just like my other example because `filters.continuousRotation` will index on `"axis"`

We are doing all of this because our target users are not programmers they are gamers and VR enthusiasts and we want a easy scipting mechanism.

http://andersmalmgren.github.io/FreePIE/

Update:
I simplified the test script to this

```
def myFunction(x):
    return filters.delta(x)

myFunction(1)
```

If i send that script through ast.parse I get object of type `_ast.Module` The first level seems straight forward, it containts a list of two items the function def and the expression which is `myFunction(1)`

[image]

Lets look hat the expr that is the functon call `myFunction(1)`

[image]

Its not super obvious how I will navigate to the function dec above from that, also the function dec should contain children of its own right? Not very obvious how that is navigated

[image]

I guess I need some rerefence manual on this object structure or a tutorial how to traverse it. The biggest question right now is how I can navigate from a `_ast.Call` to its `_ast.FunctionDef`

Comment: This is rather a broad question; did you see that the `ast` module has a [`NodeTransformer` utility class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.NodeTransformer) for example? It is based on the generic [`NodeVisitor` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.NodeVisitor) and lets you rewrite the AST on the fly based on a graph traversal. So the short answer is: *yes*, but the long answer would be: *how much time have you got to go back and forth on the details of the transformation, I don't have that much time really.*

Comment: Are `android[0].yaw` and `.pitch` numbers? What about wrapping them in a custom object that acts like a number and also contains indexer?

Comment: It will be pretty expensive to box and unbox the value types all the time. A preparser step is probably the best solution.

Comment: @Martijn, a ideal solution would be if I could convert it to a object tree structure and pass that on to the underlying c# engine and do the parsing there (I'm using iron python and the host is a. NET app)

Comment: @Anders: the [`ast.parse()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.parse) gives you just that; a Python object tree of the code in question.